# Send post notification to specific UUID android device

Tags: java, android, notifications, uuid

I'm trying to find some ways to send a post notification to specific android device using its UUID , so I will do the following :

1 : login screen on android and then get UUID number from the device

2 : send this UUID to online database linked to userID

3 : I want to know how to send post notification to a specific UUID which I get from my database ?

Comment: Have you considered using GCM for this?

Answer (score 0):

Sending notification to android device using java is very easy.

If you want to push the notification directly from REST client, then you can refer [this](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/http.html)

If you want to send notifications from your java program, then follow these simple steps,

- Add gcm-server.jar library file in your application
- Create a Sender, that will send the notification

  ```
      com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender sender = new Sender("pass your gcm api key here");
  ```
- Then create a message object that will contain the data that you want to send

  ```
  com.google.android.gcm.server.Message message = new Message.Builder().addData("key","value").build();
  ```

`addData("key","value")`  in above code will add the key value in json to be send.

- Then you can choose any of send method provided in `Sender` class

  ```
      com.google.android.gcm.server.Result result = sender.send(message, device_token, no of retries);
  ```

There are total four version of send method available. You can find more detail about Sender class [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gcm/server/Sender.html)